# Mysterious errors is Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

I wanted to reach my project folder's directory through the terminal so to make things a little easier, I simply moved the project folder onto my desktop, when doing this i was presented with this prompt:

[image]

I then pressed re-save and was presented with this prompt:

[image]

After this i moved the folder back in its original place, but when i attempt to build the app i get the following 30 `Apple Mach-O Linker Error` errors:

[image]

I attempted a clean/clean build folder... but no success. Now I have the parse and AWS SDK frameworks installed within my project, so I completely removed them both, re-inserted them, cleaned the project, build and still the same 30 errors. What seems to be the issue? I may also add i mistakenly dragged the project folder onto the desktop and out of its original folder while the app was still running. If that means anything. What can I do?

Comment: Do you have any absolute paths in the project settings or scripts maybe?

Comment: how do i find out? @Ixx

Comment: Try looking in your project's and target's build settings for strings from the path where it was previously stored... Or just scroll through them and see if you find something suspicious...

Comment: Mhh ok so because you moved it while having the project open, it complained about the missing workspace... that's normal. But the move back should have worked theoretically. Try to delete the folder `~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/`, additionally to clean and restart XCode, and try to build again.

Comment: Also, don't you get other more informative errors? A library name, a path or something?

Comment: how do i delete that folder? @Ixx

Comment: `rm -rfv ~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/` you may have to execute it multiple times, check with `ls ~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData` until it's empty/doesn't exist. Or just navigate to it with finder... `~` means your home directory.

Comment: Oh and also remove the build and target folders from your project manually... that's what clean does, but just in case. Be careful to not delete anything important though.

Comment: And if that still doesn't help remove again the frameworks, clean and build, see if the errors change. You can secure a copy from your project, and start removing one thing after the other (also files etc) until the errors change / are gone. To identify the source of the problem at least.

Comment: so i completely removed all third party frameworks from my project, meaning parse and AWS & the errors were gone. what does this mean @Ixx

Comment: hmm did you removed derived data and target etc? add only one of them, see which is the one causing problems.

Comment: i believe the derived data is gone

Comment: no the derived data us still there

Comment: it's recreated when the project is built

Comment: can i interest you in a chat? so we can make communication quicker, and get a solution?

Comment: That's what SO also suggests... but I have to sleep now. Anyway already told you everything I know / I would do... you have to dig a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an absolute path somewhere in your project's or target's settings, or a relative path pointing to a dependency outside the folder you moved. You could try to look for parts of the previous path in the settings. Alternatively with text search in a terminal, you can try something like this (in this case from the project's root directory):

```
grep -r "mypath/mypath" myproject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

Also to shed a bit more light into the issue try dragging the project back to the original folder. Is the issue fixed? If yes it's definitely a path problem.

Comment: and i dragged it back in the original folder as soon as i seen the errors, the issue never fixed.

Comment: Did you setup a git repository or any other type of version control?

Comment: no i didn't, or i would've just took it off the repo

Comment: How about a Time Machine or other backup?